# Redirección 301 en htacces multisitio

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Tengo el fichero .htaccess configurado para que varios dominios tiren de el, en un wordpress multisitio, que resuelve diferentes dominios, hasta aquí todo bien.

El problema viene cuando quiero hacer la redirección 301, unicamente para la página de un idioma:

Es decir, tengo: http://dominio.es/inicio    y  http://dominio.com/inicio   lo que necesito es redireccionar la página inicio, dentro de dominio.com pero no la página inicio, en dominio.es

En resumen:

http://dominio.es/inicio -> http://dominio.es/inicio

http://dominio.com/inicio -> http://dominio.com/home

No puedo utilizar un 301, porque me arrastra ambas páginas de inicio.
He probado

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dominio.com/inicio [NC]
RewriteRule ^inicio/$ home/ [R=301,L]
```

Pero no funciona y no consigo resolverlo.
Gracias por vuestra ayuda

---

Añado los datos reales del dominio que estoy usando por si acaso véis algo que se me ha pasado

http://teinnovacleaning.es/rtest -> http://teinnovacleaning.es/rtest

http://teinnovacleaning.com/rtest -> http://teinnovacleaning.com/home

Y mi .htaccess está así

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?teinnovacleaning\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/rtest$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^rtest$ home/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La lógica está bien en lo que intentaste, sólo hay que ajustar un poco con qué coincide y hacia dónde se redirecciona.

1. `%{HTTP_HOST}` es el host, sin la ruta.
2. En el [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), `^inicio/$` tiene una barra al final que hace que no coincida, y la podemos hacer opcional.

```py
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dominio\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^inicio/?$ home [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Efectivamente esta era la respuesta